# Multi-tenancy on tomcat

Tags: java, json, tomcat

I've set of JSON APIs that are exposed and implemented on Tomcat.
I would like to implement Multi-tenancy for these APIs on Tomcat with the following URL approach:

```
companyname1.domain.com/api/getUsers...
companyname2.domain.com/api/getUsers...
companyname3.domain.com/api/getUsers...
```

Let me know if there is a best practice for implementing it using context or other mechanism. I don't want to create a separate Tomcat instance for each and every company.
In addition is there any way to create it dynamically once company is registered.

Thank you in advance,
Moshe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create several [virtual hosts](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html) in your Tomcats **server.xml**, that listen to your domains. These should point to **different webapps directories**, hosting your particular application in the **ROOT** directory:

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="domain1-webapps" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true"></Host>
<Host name="companyname1.domain.com" appBase="domain1-webapps" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true"></Host>
<Host name="companyname2.domain.com" appBase="domain2-webapps" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true"></Host>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using multiple reverse proxies that provide different parameters to the Tomcat webapp. The simplest setup (with Apache HTTP and [mod_proxy_ajp](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html)) would probably be to preserve the original request's host and resolve that inside the web app.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName companyname1.domain.com

    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName companyname2.domain.com

    ProxyPass /api ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName companyname3.domain.com

    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I can not comment because of my reputation is below than 50.

if URI is same like 
companyname1.domain.com/api/getUsers
companyname2.domain.com/api/getUsers
companyname3.domain.com/api/getUsers

then Apache web server found domain companyname1.domain.com and from httpd file, it send call to tomcat application server through AJP connector. But problem is that how can it found which war file to run.
```

So application name is required in URL

```
companyname1.domain.com/abc/api/getUsers
companyname2.domain.com/xyz/api/getUsers
companyname3.domain.com/fgf/api/getUsers
```

Answer (score 0):

```
We can use server context setting. As per tomcat server specification. 

The Host element represents a virtual host, which is an association of a network name for a server (such as "www.mycompany.com") 
with the particular server on which Tomcat is running. For clients to be able to connect to a Tomcat server using its network name,
this name must be registered in the Domain Name Service (DNS) server that manages the Internet domain you belong to - contact your Network Administrator 
for more information.
    
In many cases, System Administrators wish to associate more than one network name (such as www.mycompany.com and company.com) 
with the same virtual host and applications. This can be accomplished using the Host Name Aliases feature discussed below.
    
One or more Host elements are nested inside an Engine element. 
Inside the Host element, you can nest Context elements for the web applications associated with this virtual host. 
Exactly one of the Hosts associated with each Engine MUST have a name matching the defaultHost attribute of that Engine.
    
Clients normally use host names to identify the server they wish to connect to. This host name is also included in the HTTP request headers. 
Tomcat extracts the host name from the HTTP headers and looks for a Host with a matching name. 
If no match is found, the request is routed to the default host. 
The name of the default host does not have to match a DNS name (although it can) since any request where the 
DNS name does not match the name of a Host element will be routed to the default host.

For more info. go through this link. 
:https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/host.html
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me a lot